# If parents with permanent residency visas arrive in Australia with their two babies who don't have permanent residency visas, can they be turned away?

Tags: visas, australia

My partner and I, and our first son were granted Permanent Residency visas for Australia a couple of years ago. Since then we've had 2 more kids. We're all Irish.

We're now ready to make the move, but we've since discovered that we need to get the same Visas for the 2 new children.

The embassy says that we need to get the visas before bringing them into the country.

What are our options?

Would it be possible for us to get visitor visas for them and then apply for the children's permanent residency visas when we arrive?

Is there a risk that they'd be turned away by the border police if they arrive in the country on a 1-way ticket with visitor visas, even if they're in the company of their parents and brother - all of whom have the permanent residency visas?

Comment: This probably belongs on expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Will I delete it and add it over there?

Comment: No need, the moderators have magic powers to move it if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your embassy has already told you that your children have to be added to your visa, and the [Australian Immigration website says the same](http://www.immi.gov.au/Live/Pages/children-born-to-a-permanent-resident-of-australia.aspx):

> Children born outside Australia to permanent resident parents will
>   need to apply for and be granted a permanent visa to be able to enter
>   and remain in Australia with their parents.

Now that wording is a little ambiguous: they'll (obviously!) need the permanent residence to enter *and remain*, but you're asking about entering only.

In practice, if you showed up at the border with valid eVisitor visas for your younger children, they *could* turn you away because they'd have very valid grounds to suspect they're not leaving, but they would *probably* let you all in.  However, this would almost certainly cause you hassle:

1. when entering the country, especially if you don't have tickets out within the 90 days an eVisitor permits;
2. if your children's PR is granted, since skilled migration visas are usually only granted outside Australia; and
3. if your children's PR is *not* granted within 90 days, since they'll have to leave the country!

So I'd recommend filing the paperwork to get your children added to your PR right now -- it should only be a formality, although Abbott knows DIBP can still take their sweet time processing it -- and cooling your heels until it's granted.

Comment: I reckon you're right, but it's unfortunate. I don't see it as any more than a arbitrary bureaucratic rule and it's going to cost us a lot of time. We've already started on the paperwork so I guess we just wait now.